# CodeIgniter problem with limit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a LoteModel:

```
public function selecionar($where = NULL, $limit = NULL, $order_by = NULL) {
            if(!is_null($where)) {
                $this->db->where($where);
            }
            if(!is_null($limit)) {
                $this->db->limit($limit);
            }
            if(!is_null($order_by)) {
                $this->db->order_by($order_by);
            }

            return $this->db->get(_LOTE_);//_LOTE_ is a constant for my table name
    }
```

and I call it like this:

```
$config['per_page'] = '5';

$limite = $config['per_page'].','.$this->uri->segment(3); //the segment is ok, I receive it

$lotes = $this->LoteModel->selecionar(array('quadra_id'=>$quadra_id, 'lote_status'=>1), $limite, 'lote_endereco');
```

I have checked the SQL result for that query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`realestate_lote`) WHERE `quadra_id` = '1' AND `lote_status` = 1 ORDER BY `lote_endereco`
```

The thing is, it’s not generating my LIMIT, it will only work if I add it to the LoteModel method.

I’m working with pagination.

Thanks in advance for any help =)

Comment: I have found the problem but not the solution:

The LIMIT only accepts LIMIT(10,20) and not LIMIT(‘10,20’) as I’m doing.

I don’t know how to solve this, anyone?

Comment: I found a way to solve it.

I can send a array as my LIMIT parameter:

$lotes = $this->LoteModel->selecionar(array('quadra_id'=>$quadra_id, 'lote_status'=>1), array('x'=>10, 'y'=>20), 'lote_endereco');

Or change my LoteModel to:

public function selecionar($where = NULL, $limit_start = NULL, $limit_end = NULL, $order_by = NULL) {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a string like "5,1" to CI's ActiveRecord limit function.
The function requires two parameters.

Split the limit string by "," and pass the two values like the example below.

```
$limit = explode(',', $limit);
$this->db->limit($limit[0], $limit[1]);
```

Hope this helps...